# Run multiple commands in the same shell process

Tags: ruby, shell

I'm attempting to run a series of commands through Ruby, and capture `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and the exitstatus.

```
require "open3"
require "pp"

command_list = [
  "export MY_ENV_VAR=foobar",
  "printenv MY_ENV_VAR"
]

executed_commands = []
result = nil

command_list.each do |command|
  stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command)
  result = status.exitstatus
  executed_commands << [command, stdout, stderr, result]
  break if result != 0
end

pp executed_commands
puts "exited with #{result} exit status."
```

This process exits with a non-zero status, indicating that the `printenv MY_ENV_VAR` command fails, and that the commands are not being run in the same process.

**How can I execute a series of commands in a single shell process, recording `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and the exitstatus of each command?**

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest you don't chain together multiple shell commands into a single system call if you don't absolutely have to. A major caveat is that you can't individually inspect the return codes of each command in the chain. This leads to lack of control over the command flow. For example, if the first command in the chain fails for any reason, the subsequent commands will still attempt to execute regardless of the state of the first command. This may be undesirable.

I suggest encapsulating the popen functionality into a method and just call the method for each command you want to run. This would allow you to react to any failed execution on a command-by-command basis.

Comment: When running multiple commands in one call, though you can't individually inspect the return codes, you can avoid the problem of continuing on failure by joining the commands with `&&` instead of `;`.

Comment: That is true.
As a rule of thumb I'd be more comfortable handling this more verbosely. Again, if you don't have a strict technical reason to combine commands, avoid it. Plus there are security implications to this method, but that is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code for running a series of commands is fine.  The issue is that you were setting the environment variable incorrectly.  A child process cannot set the environment of its parent like you were trying to do.  Child processes do inherit the environment of their parent, so here is one way to fix your code:

```
require "open3"
require "pp"

ENV['MY_ENV_VAR'] = 'hi'

command_list = [
  "printenv MY_ENV_VAR"
]

executed_commands = []
result = nil

command_list.each do |command|
  stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command)
  result = status.exitstatus
  executed_commands << [command, stdout, stderr, result]
  break if result != 0
end

pp executed_commands
puts "exited with #{result} exit status."
```

The result when I run this on Linux with Ruby 2.3.1 is:

```
[["printenv MY_ENV_VAR", "hi\n", "", 0]]
exited with 0 exit status.
```

Now if you wanted to pass an environment variable to the child process without modifying your own process's environment, see the documentation for the arguments of `Open3.capture3`:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3

Comment: How would I create a parent shell process, and then execute a series of commands in that shell?

Comment: You could try separating putting multiple commands in one string and separating them with `&&` or `;`.  I recommend the former since it will stop whenever there is an error.